# Unknown column in 'on clause' - tried both where and having conditions but same error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT hh_podcast_channel.id
FROM hh_podcast_channel
inner JOIN (
        SELECT hh_podcast_episodes.podcast_id, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hh_podcast_episodes.id ORDER BY hh_podcast_episodes.published_on) as rn
        FROM hh_podcast_episodes
    ) as t2
    ON hh_podcast_channel.id = hh_podcast_episodes.podcast_id
having t2.rn = 1
```

> #1054 - Unknown column 'hh_podcast_episodes.podcast_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: You've aliased your sub-query as "t2", so the JOIN needs to be ON hh_podcast_channel.id = t2.podcast_id

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the table alias (t2) in the JOIN condition

```
SELECT hh_podcast_channel.id 
FROM hh_podcast_channel inner JOIN 
(
    SELECT hh_podcast_episodes.podcast_id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hh_podcast_episodes.id
    ORDER BY hh_podcast_episodes.published_on) as rn 
    FROM hh_podcast_episodes
) 
as t2 ON hh_podcast_channel.id = t2.podcast_id 
having t2.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I tried using the query it gives 504 error stating error in processing request after taking some time for execution.

Comment: Well, that's an error indicating a timeout of some sort - so now that you've got a query that can successfully compile and execute, you're now discovering that you've obviously got a large amount of data to query resulting in a timeout

Comment: Do you know how many rows you have in each table?

Comment: Try running the sub-query on its own and see if it times out - or you could add a limit on the end of the full query and see if it completes (eg. add LIMIT 10 on the end)

Answer (score 0):

Why you even use the subquery in join. Use the `row_number` in main query and then use it in the subquery for simplicity as follows:

```
Select id from
(SELECT t1.id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.id ORDER BY t2.published_on) as rn
  FROM hh_podcast_channel t1
  JOIN hh_podcast_episodes t2
    On t1.id = t2.podcast_id) t
Where rn = 1
```

Comment: I tried using the query but it gives 504 error stating error in processing request after taking some time for execution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT pc.id
FROM hh_podcast_channel pc JOIN
     (SELECT pe.*
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pe.id ORDER BY pe.published_on) as rn
      FROM hh_podcast_episodes pe
     ) pe
     ON pc.id = pe.podcast_id
WHERE pe.rn = 1;
```

This fixes your specific problem which is that your table aliases are confused.  In addition:

- This uses *meaningful* table aliases, which are abbreviations for the column names.
- This replaces the `HAVING` with `WHERE`.  Although both happen to work in MySQL, the use of `HAVING` is misleading because it implies aggregation.
- This uses `pe.*`, relying on the optimizer to choose the columns in the subquery.  I just find that that is more convenient, so if I decide to include another column, I don't have to make changes in multiple places.

I also suspect that you want `SELECT DISTINCT`, but your question doesn't provide sample data and desired results.